# webview get current url Net MAUI

Tags: android, webview, maui

I've just started learning Net MAUI. Faced with the fact that I need to get and save the last visited link in a webview. If everything is clear with saving (I have already implemented functions for this), then getting the current link is still difficult for me

My code looks like this at the moment, but there is still no saving

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string infor = Preferences.Default.Get("uriInfo", "https://www.google.com/").ToString();
    webhtmlll.Source = infor;
    webhtmlll.Reload();

   

    if (OnBackButtonPressed() && webhtmlll.CanGoBack)
    {
        webhtmlll.GoBack();
    }
}

//получение ссылки
private void webview_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    var webView = sender as WebView;
    var html = (webView.Source as UrlWebViewSource).Url;

    Preferences.Default.Set("uriInfo", html.ToString());
}

protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    if (webhtmlll.CanGoBack)
    {
        webhtmlll.GoBack();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnBackButtonPressed();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: use the [Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?pivots=devices-android#perform-navigation) events

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Navigated` event to detect the HTML .

In the .xaml

```
<WebView x:Name="webview" ... Navigated="webview_Navigated" />
<Label x:Name="label" />
```

In the code behind:

```
 private void webview_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
 {

            var webView = sender as WebView;

            var html = (webView.Source as UrlWebViewSource).Url;

            label.Text = html.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: I edited the code in the question a little, according to your advice, but the last link is still not saved, you can see what's wrong

Comment: You can make a breakpoint at your save method and then check if it is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Use e.Url instead of webView.Source.

Source will always be the same even after navigation of the webview.